# Как сделать автозапуск XAMPP на Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xampp, автозапуск

Как сделать автозапуск XAMPP на Ubuntu?
Нужно, чтобы запускался XAMPP автоматически при включении компьютера.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/870115

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто откройте терминал и напишите:

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Редактор на ваше усмотрение, если нет `gedit`, можно любой другой (nano, vim, pluma и т.д.)

А затем нужно добавить эти 2 строки перед последней строкой:

```
cd /opt/lampp/
sudo ./lampp start
```

И это все. Просто сохраните и перезагрузите компьютер. Обратите внимание, что эти строки должны быть выше последней строки, которая говорит `exit 0`

Ответ @Muhammad bin Yusrat

Обратите внимание там по ссылке 2 ответа, оба рабочие, но этот ответ проще.
Если же вы будете добавлять какой-либо готовый скрипт для этого, помните, что ему надо дать необходимые права.

Также спасибо @Suvitruf за найденный источник

[Источник 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870099/auto-start-xampp-in-ubuntu-16-04/870115#870115)
[Источник 2](https://itshaman.ru/articles/71/install-settings-web-server-xampp)